# geom_bar at gg plot ruins order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data.table

```
decomp1 <- data.table(V2 = c("Sp", "Sp", "Su", "Sp", "Su", "Su", "X", 
                      "Su", "X", "Su", "X", "X", "Sp", "Sp", "X", "Su", "X", "Sp", 
                      "X", "Su", "Sp", "Su", "Su", "X", "Sp", "Sp", "Sp", "Su", "Su", 
                      "X", "Sp", "Sp", "X", "Su", "X", "Su", "Sp", "X", "Su", "Sp", 
                      "Sp", "Su"), 
               V3 = c("Sp", "Sp", "Su_6", "Sp", "Su_6", "Su_6", 
                                          "X", "Su_6", "X", "Su_6", "X", "X", "Sp", "Sp", "X", "Su_6", 
                                          "X", "Sp", "X", "Su_6", "Sp", "Su_6", "Su_6", "X", "Sp", "Sp", 
                                          "Sp", "Su_6", "Su_6", "X", "Sp", "Sp", "X", "Su_6", "X", "Su_6", 
                                          "Sp", "X", "Su_6", "Sp", "Sp", "Su_6"),
               V4 = c("Va", "Va", "Pr", 
                      "Va", "Pr", "Pr", "Tr", "He", "He", "He", "Tr", "He", "He", "He", 
                      "Tr", "He", "He", "He", "Qu", "Qu", "Qu", "Qu", "NP", "Qu", "Qu", 
                      "NP", "Qu", "NP", "Qu", "Qu", "NP", "NP", "NP", "NP", "NP", "Tr", 
                      "Tr", "NP", "Tr", "Tr", "Tr", "Tr"), 
               V5 = c("Non", "Long", "Non", 
                      "Ca", "Long", "Ca", "Non", "Non", "Non", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
                      "Non", "Long", "Ca", "Ca", "Ca", "Ca", "Non", "Non", "Non", "Long", 
                      "Non", "Long", "Long", "Non", "Ca", "Long", "Ca", "Ca", "Long", 
                      "Ca", "Non", "Ca", "Long", "Non", "Non", "Ca", "Long", "Long", 
                      "Ca", "Ca"), 
               V6 = c("Total", "Total", "Total", "Total", "Total", 
                      "Total", "Total", "Total", "Total", "Total", "Total", "Total", 
                      "Total", "Total", "Total", "Total", "Total", "Total", "Total", 
                      "Total", "Total", "Total", "Total", "Total", "Total", "Total", 
                      "Total", "Total", "Total", "Total", "Total", "Total", "Total", 
                      "Total", "Total", "Total", "Total", "Total", "Total", "Total", 
                      "Total", "Total"), 
               V1 = c("0.072384480,", "0.005913364,", "0.084688599,", 
                      "0.014997295,", "0.010088229,", "0.020780549,", "0.244325980,", 
                      "0.269335944,", "0.282962793,", "0.018655723,", "0.051010924,", 
                      "0.014688654,", "0.298544133,", "0.026934186,", "0.052777085,", 
                      "0.060859581,", "0.051597466,", "0.025747971,", "0.374481663,", 
                      "0.379704887,", "0.390599270,", "0.030278558,", "0.410034427,", 
                      "0.051577777,", "0.035755516,", "0.440449409,", "0.016192095,", 
                      "0.040907457,", "0.050172704,", "0.037228066,", "0.033683551,", 
                      "0.016825497,", "0.493787903,", "0.045299959,", "0.032781898,", 
                      "0.556733851,", "0.577734392,", "0.063572428,", "0.038519396,", 
                      "0.039316251,", "0.017420358,", "0.044930589)"), 
               V7 = c(0.07238448, 
                      0.07829784, 0.0846886, 0.09329514, 0.09477683, 0.11555738, 0.24432598, 
                      0.26933594, 0.28296279, 0.28799167, 0.2953369, 0.29765145, 0.29854413, 
                      0.32547832, 0.34811399, 0.34885125, 0.34924891, 0.35122629, 0.37448166, 
                      0.37970489, 0.39059927, 0.40998344, 0.41003443, 0.42605944, 0.42635479, 
                      0.44044941, 0.44254688, 0.45094188, 0.46015615, 0.46328751, 0.47413296, 
                      0.49095846, 0.4937879, 0.49624184, 0.5265698, 0.55673385, 0.57773439, 
                      0.59014223, 0.59525325, 0.61705064, 0.634471, 0.64018384))
```

and i run

```
print(ggplot(decomp1,aes(x=V4,y=V1,fill=V5,label=paste0(round(V1,3)*100,"%")))+theme_pl()+geom_bar(stat = "identity",aes(width=0.5))+facet_grid(V3~.)+
        scale_fill_manual(values = c(c("Non"="#1581A4", "Long"="#FFA600", "Ca"="#B50000")))+
        scale_y_continuous(label=percent,limits = c(0,0.7))+
        theme(legend.title=element_blank(),axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.title.y = element_blank())+
        geom_text(aes(y=V7-V1/2),col="white",size=3)+
        geom_text(data=decomp1[,.(V1=sum(V1),V5="Non"),by=.(V4,V3)],aes(y=V1,vjust=-1,fontface="bold")))
```

and i get as output [image]

As you can see the "colors" are not in the correct order. So actually what I would like to have in the end, is the same plot, with the same numbers but the order of the colors (from bottom to top), in each column in each row, should be blue > yellow > red, and not red > yellow > blue. I dont know why is this happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of ggplot2 are you running under? The following:

```
ggplot(decomp1, aes(x=V4,y=V1,fill=V5, label=paste0(round(V1,3)*100,"%"))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.5) +
  geom_text(aes(y=V7-V1/2), col="white", size=3) +
  geom_text(data=decomp1[,.(V1=sum(V1),V5="Non"), by=.(V4,V3)], 
            aes(y=V1, vjust=-1), fontface="bold") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("Non"="#1581A4", "Long"="#FFA600", "Ca"="#B50000")) +
  scale_y_continuous(label=scales::percent,limits = c(0,0.7)) +
  facet_grid(V3~.) +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

Generates:

[image]

Under the most recent ggplot2 pkg.

We don't have `theme_pl()`, hence the difference in theme aesthetics.

I *did* move some things outside of `aes()` that didn't belong there and organized the plot code better (I can't imagine debugging anything in the original format) but factor order determine bar segment order and it seems to be working fine with up-to-date pkgs.

---

```
> session_info()
Session info -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
 system   x86_64, darwin13.4.0        
 ui       RStudio (1.0.136)           
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
 tz       America/New_York            
 date     2016-12-16                  

Packages -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package    * version    date       source                         
 assertthat   0.1        2013-12-06 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                 
 colorspace   1.2-6      2015-03-11 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                 
 data.table * 1.9.8      2016-11-25 cran (@1.9.8)                  
 devtools   * 1.12.0     2016-06-24 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                 
 digest       0.6.10     2016-08-02 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                 
 ggplot2    * 2.2.0.9000 2016-12-16 Github (hadley/ggplot2@f6f9f9d)
 gtable       0.2.0      2016-02-26 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                 
 labeling     0.3        2014-08-23 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                 
 lazyeval     0.2.0      2016-06-12 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                 
 magrittr     1.5        2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                 
 memoise      1.0.0      2016-01-29 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                 
 munsell      0.4.3      2016-02-13 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                 
 plyr         1.8.4      2016-06-08 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                 
 Rcpp         0.12.8     2016-11-17 CRAN (R 3.3.2)                 
 reshape2     1.4.2      2016-10-22 cran (@1.4.2)                  
 rstudioapi   0.6        2016-06-27 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                 
 scales       0.4.1.9000 2016-12-16 Github (hadley/scales@89c2a2f) 
 stringi      1.1.2      2016-10-01 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                 
 stringr      1.1.0      2016-08-19 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                 
 tibble       1.2        2016-08-26 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                 
 withr        1.0.2      2016-06-20 CRAN (R 3.3.0)
```

Comment: which version of ggplot2 do you have ?

Comment: i have version 2.2.0

Comment: session info added. you shld prbly `dput()` your data table as you've prbly munged factors somewhere. I tried including a programmatic way to read said table in for others to help without having to deal with a useless pasted print table output but someone seems to have removed it from your question